# How to get selected item from the Action Bar drop-down navigation outside onNavigationItemSelected android

Tags: android

I want to get the selected item value of the Action Bar drop-down navigation from outside of the below code

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    mSelected.setText("Selected: " + mLocations[itemPosition]);//I want this selected item from the below code
```

I want to get the selected item from inside the below code

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    int selected_item__position = //here I want to get the selected item from the Action bar drop down
```

Comment: is this possible? any help.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I came up with a solution like this but I don't know if it's a good idea to do it this way or not

```
public TextView tv_selected_item_value;
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    mSelected.setText("Selected: " + mLocations[itemPosition]);
    tv_selected_item_value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv_selected_item_value.setText(mLocations[itemPosition]);}

 @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
selected_item_value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```